# How to write a macro used in cond in clojure?

Tags: macros, clojure

I have the following macro to ensure the data containing specific keys.

```
(defmacro with-correct-format
  [data & body]
  `(cond
    (nil? ~data) (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                        "input data cannot be nil"))
    (nil? (:first-name data)) (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                              "first name cannot be nil"))
    (nil? (:last-name data)) (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                             "last name cannot be nil"))
    :else ~@body))
```

I want to refactor this code by extracting the `(nil? (:key data))` condition. I tried this one but not working:

```
(defmacro key?
  [key-name data]
  `((nil? (~key-name ~data)) (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                             "cannot be nil"))))
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it would probably be best to avoid macros entirely for this--there's not really anything that's requiring this to take the form of a macro, so stick to functions.

Then what you're trying to capture as a macro becomes a function we can `map` over.

```
(defn check-data 
  [data]
  (if (nil? data)
      (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "input data cannot be nil."))
      (dorun (map #(when (nil? (% data)) (throw (IllegalArgumentException. 
                                                  (str % " cannot be nil"))))
                  [:first-name :last-name]))))
```

then (with-correct-format data body ...) just becomes (do (check-data data) body ...)

Keep in mind that, with a macro, the expansion of `data` could be evaluated multiple times with your current implementation.

Comment: Agreed. Macros should be avoided except for things that are not possible with functions, which this certainly is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't show us how you are using `key?` or what "not working means", but (1) `((nil? ...` should be `(list (nil? ...)` otherwise you are invoking the result of `nil?` and (2) you are missing some unquotes `~` on `data` in the first macro. But yeah, macros aren't called for here...

```
(defn bar [data] 
  {:pre [(:first-name data), (:last-name data)]} 
  (println "This data passed:" (pr-str data)))
```

---

```
so.core=> (bar nil)
AssertionError Assert failed: (:first-name data)  so.core/bar ...

so.core=> (bar {:first-name "joe"})
AssertionError Assert failed: (:last-name data)  so.core/bar ...

so.core=> (bar {:first-name "joe", :last-name "smith"})
This data passed: {:last-name "smith", :first-name "joe"}
```

Comment: Preconditions are probably the most idiomatic way to do this. +1